# langchain agent_scratchpad input key error

Tags: python, agent, langchain, large-language-model, py-langchain

```
from langchain.llms import LlamaCpp
from langchain import PromptTemplate, LLMChain
from langchain.callbacks.manager import CallbackManager
from langchain.callbacks.streaming_stdout import StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler

from langchain.agents import Tool, AgentExecutor, initialize_agent, AgentType, Agent
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
from langchain.chains import LLMChain

from langchain.agents.conversational.base import ConversationalAgent

tools = [
]

callback_manager = CallbackManager([StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()])

llm = LlamaCpp(
    model_path="llama-2-7b-chat.Q4_K_M.gguf",
    input={"temperature": 0.75,
    "max_length": 10000,
    top_p": 0.1},
    callback_manager=callback_manager,
    verbose=True
    )


prefix = """
You are a chatbot having a conversation with a human. Keep your response concise, within 500 characters. 
"""

suffix = """Begin!

{chat_history}

User: {human_input}
{agent_scratchpad}
Chatbot: 
"""

#ai_prefix = """"""
#human_prefix = """"""



memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history", return_messages=True)

prompt = ConversationalAgent.create_prompt(
    tools, 
    prefix=prefix, 
    suffix=suffix, 
    input_variables=["human_input", "chat_history", "agent_scratchpad"]
    )


llm_chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=prompt, memory=memory)

agent = ConversationalAgent(
    llm_chain=llm_chain, 
    tools=tools, 
    verbose=True,
    prompt=prompt,
)


agent_executor = AgentExecutor.from_agent_and_tools(
    agent=agent, 
    tools=tools, 
    memory=memory
    )


resp = agent_executor.run(human_input = "Hi")
```

This is my code. The tools will be added later. I want to create a single conversational agent capable of remembering conversation content with langchain. However, when I use this code:

> ValueError: One input key expected got ['agent_scratchpad', 'human_input']

It shows this error. I also tried removing the 'agent_scratchpad', but I encountered another error indicating it is an essential component.

How should I bring in the 'agent_scratchpad'?

I also tried removing the 'agent_scratchpad', but I encountered another error indicating it is an essential component.

I tried changing the order of input_variables and also experimented with different suffix prompts.

And the ZeroshotAgent didn't encounter this error.

Comment: Put full traceback in the post. Otherwise, it is complicated to find out where the problem is.